# Code not working when debug off

Tags: apex, trigger

When I have the debug log turned off, the code below will not be executed.

```
    for (Opportunity opportunityObject : Trigger.New){
        if(Trigger.isUpdate) {
            if(docusignRtIdList.contains(opportunityObject.RecordTypeId)) {
                if(opportunityObject.StageName == 'Aguardando Assinatura' && System.Trigger.oldMap.get(opportunityObject.Id).StageName != 'Aguardando Assinatura') {
                    ExceptionManager.saveMessage('Aguardando Assinatura', 'OpportunityPDFTrigger', 'AfterUpdate', opportunityObject.Id, 'DEBUG');
                    RecordType recordTypeObject = [SELECT Name FROM RecordType WHERE Id = :opportunityObject.RecordTypeId AND SObjectType = 'Opportunity' LIMIT 1];
                    Boolean lic = opportunityObject.OwnerId == '00540000001TUHM' ? true : false;
                    //@future(callout=true)
                    Service_Docusign.generateOpportunityDocusignPDF(opportunityObject.Id, recordTypeObject.Name, lic);  

                }
            }   
        } 
    }
```

If I try to run the same thing, but now, with the debug log turned on, everything will run as intended.

Has someone ever seen something like this before?
Is it something with the future method?

Comment: none of the code executes? of the PDF doesn't generate? It is highly unlikely to have anything to do with debug log on/off

Comment: Our users were having problem when running this flow. Then when we turned the debug log to monitor what was happening to them, it worked.

That's how we found, and managed to reproduce the error

Comment: Historically, there has been functionality that works or breaks based on debug logs. It's not out of the realm of possibility. Here's an *active* known issue where debug logs play a role in functionality: https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000001RXPlQAO

Comment: I totally understand - anything is possible! That said, your example is a method that misbehaves with only one input type and does not prevent execution - just offers the wrong result. Saying an entire trigger execution is skipped (could be thousands of lines of code) just because of the debug is off is a bit harder for me to acknowledge. Hey! I might be wrong - but I would exhaust every possibility before opening that support case.

Answer (score 2):

We have a scenario very similar -- it's a validation run through a trigger. We've done multiple tests where, literally, the only thing we change is activating a debug trace on the running user.

If the debug is on, the trigger works.
If the debug is off, the trigger doesn't work (validation always blocks insert of record).

In fact, one of my favorite tests is clicking the save button without a debug trace and watching the page pop up with an error. Then, after turning on the debug trace and clicking the save button a second time (doing ABSOLUTELY NOTHING ELSE) the trigger suddenly begins working properly and only blocks records that should be blocked.

There is a bug here.

---

### ----------------UPDATE------------------

Looks like this could actually be a bug:
[success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000001RXPlQAO](http://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000001RXPlQAO)

Comment: I highly doubt there is a bug preventing code execution based on logging (it is possible, just saying it is highly unlikely). Do you have other triggers on this object? Trigger order of execution cannot be guaranteed so maybe another trigger is doing something and breaking prior to reaching this one. Could that be the case? I'm wondering if there is a trace flag on the trigger, maybe it is prioritized in terms of the order of execution. Do you have a trace on the trigger?

Comment: @identigral: Merely trying to bolster that this does indeed seem to be a bug (an answer that there may be no answer). Here is a link to an issue that seems to be debug related: https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000001RXPlQAO

Comment: @zthroescha The 'this is a bug, here's a link to a KI' is an acceptable answer. Please update your answer rather than having it in a comment

Answer (score 1):

- Firstly, if(Trigger.isUpdate) should be the outermost tag (to only check once)
- Secondly, NEVER HARDCODE IDs !!!! Create a custom label and reference it in your code.
- Having debug logs on or off will not alter the execution logic, so something must be off with your methods ExceptionManager.saveMessage or Service_Docusign.generateOpportunityDocusignPDF
- The future execution can be monitored in Setup -> Apex Jobs

Comment: When I check Setup -> Apex Jobs. It has entries for those times where I had my Debug Log enabled.

It seems that my trigger won't even run when debug is off. 
I've never seen it before.


Also, ExceptionManager.saveMessage will insert an object so we can gather info with debug off. So it wasn't there when we first created the code.

Comment: If it helps.

This is triggered from an Approval Process that changes the opportunity StageName

Comment: I should have mentioned that maybe some of the criteria is not met (stageName not changed correctly) OR incorrect opportunityObject.RecordTypeId. I know you are seeing the behavior when turning the debugs on or off, but I can assure you there is something else causing the behavior which caused you to draw the wrong conclusion.